# Quicksort (from the book Programming perls)

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to learn all I can about sorting algorithms. On today's agenda is the Quicksort. Heres what I got.

QuickSort Class:

```
import java.util.*;

  public class QuickSort{
    public static void swap(int A[], int x ,int y){
      int temp = A[x];
      A[x] = A[y];
      A[y] = temp;
    }

     public static int[] QSort(int A[], int L, int U){
       Random randomGenerator = new Random();

       if (L >= U){
         System.out.printf("The value of L: %d, U: %d\n",L,U);
         return A; // Sorted.

       }

       if (L < U ){
         int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(U);
         swap( A, L, randomInt);
         int T = A[L];
         int M = L;

       for (int i = L+1;i < U; i++){
         if ( A[i] < T){
           M = M+1;
           swap(A, M, i);
         }
       }
       swap(A, L, M);
       QSort(A, L, M-1 );
       QSort(A, M+1, U );
    }

     //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
     return A;
   }

 }
```

The Main:

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class Main{
   public static void main(String [] args){

     int[] intArray =  {1,3,2,4,56,0,4,2,4,7,80,120,99,9,10,67};

     System.out.printf("Original Array was: %s\n\n",Arrays.toString(intArray));

     System.out.printf("Size of Array is: %d\n",intArray.length);
     QuickSort qs = new QuickSort();
     int[] A = qs.QSort(intArray, 5, intArray.length);
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
 }
```

}

Well that's all have till now. The code compiles and everything but the sorting algorithm is wrong. I am trying to understand logically whats happening in the QuickSort algorithm and used the book Programming Perls to aid my understanding.

Here's the list of questions I have:

1. In the QuickSort class in the for loop according to the book, "i's" conditional clause needs to be "i <=U" but if I do that the code gives me an 'Array index out of bounds' error. Why is that happening ? I know what an 'array index out of bounds' error is, I just can't grasp why the array location wont exist?
2. The first if clause checks to see if the array is sorted. When I compile the code this clause is meet on the first try(which should not happen in the first place). And if it is why isn't the function ended via the return A line?

The book I am using is by John Bentley page 112.

Comment: I would use your debugger to debug your code and see what it is doing rather than what you think it should be doing.

Comment: I think int[] A = qs.QSort(intArray, 5, intArray.length); should be intArray.length-1;

Comment: For your point 2, how do you think it enters the if clause condition if it does not return with A?

Comment: @Bansal that's my bad, I has trying to understand the logic and put 5 there to see what happens. The line should actually be qs.QSort(intArray,1,intArray.length) from pg 111 of the book.

Comment: It should still be int[] A = qs.QSort(intArray, 1, intArray.length-1); for zero based indexing.

Comment: @Bansal, I made a print statement before to see. It printed out 16 times again and again on each run. That's how I knew it was in the if statement.

Comment: Three side notes: **(1)** Use java naming conventions, the QSort() method should be `qSort()` (methods start with smaller case). **(2)** Use one random generator rather then creating a new one for each invokation of `QSort()` - will make your life easier to reproduce errors (by placing a constant seed during development stage). **(3)** Since `Qsort()` is static method, no need for an instance of `QuickSort()`, you can invoke with `QuickSort.QSort(...)`

Comment: @amit you are right I am a C programmer lol. Just diversifying my skill set!

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest No worries, I am just giving you advises to improve, everyone makes mistakes - just helping you to be aware of them. good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line : `int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(U);`

You should get a random int between L and U, by using:

```
int randomInt = L + randomGenerator.nextInt(U - L);
```

Also, if you want U to be the largest index in the array, you shoule pass to it `intArray.length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from other anomalies already pointed out,

Your question 1:
As already stated the initial value for U should be `intArray.length - 1`.

```
int[] A = qs.QSort(intArray, 5, intArray.length - 1 );
```

Your question 2:
The first if clause does not check if the array is sorted, it just checks whether the U and L pointers have crossed each other or not.

**For quicksort, this means that for the current pivot, all items less than pivot are to its left and all elements greater than pivot are to its right.**

This crossing may happen multiple times during the sort depending on the number of pivot changes required to completely sort the array.

For more information on quicksort, following link may be helpful. http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/sequencing/sort-algorithms/quicksort/

Comment: No, it's not necessary for the upper bound to be the largest valid index. It **may** be so, but then upper bound of the partition loop should be changed (with `i <= U`).

Comment: @chill yes that is exactly OP's first question.

Answer (score 1):

In your invocation of `QSort` the upper bound is exclusive

```
QSort(A, L, M-1 );
```

but here you miss to sort the number at index `M-1`.

It should be

```
QSort (A, L, M);
```

PS. and what @LeeNeverGup said about the random.

Basically, this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class QSort {
    public static void swap(int A[], int x, int y) {
        int temp = A[x];
        A[x] = A[y];
        A[y] = temp;
    }

    public static void sort (int A[], int L, int U) {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        if (L + 1 >= U)
            return;

        int randomInt = L + randomGenerator.nextInt(U - L);
        swap(A, L, randomInt);
        int T = A[L];
        int M = L;

        for (int i = L + 1; i < U; i++) {
            if (A[i] < T) {
                M = M + 1;
                swap(A, M, i);
            }
        }
        swap(A, L, M);
        sort(A, L, M);
        sort(A, M + 1, U);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] intArray =
            { 1, 3, 2, 4, 56, 0, 4, 2, 4, 7, 80, 120, 99, 9, 10, 67 };

        System.out.printf(  "Original Array was: %s\n\n",
                            Arrays.toString(intArray));

        System.out.printf("Size of Array is: %d\n", intArray.length);
        QSort.sort (intArray, 0, intArray.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
    }
}
```